# How to split Java String using REGEX into array

Tags: java, regex, string

I have got a Java String as follows:

C|51199120|36937872|14261248|0.73|I|102398308|6240560|96157748|0.07|J|90598564|1920184|8867    8380|0.0

I want split this using regex as String arrays:

```
Array1 = C,51199120,36937872,14261248,0.73
Array2 =I,102398308,6240560,96157748,0.07
Array3 =J,90598564,1920184,88678380,0.03
```

Can Anybody help with Java code?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the String[] split(String regex) method in the Java API?

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Just split it on `|` and then take groups of 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that simple.  You have two things you need to do:

1. Break up the input string when you encounter a letter
2. Break up each substring by the pipe

I'm no regex expert, but I don't think it can be a single pattern.  You need two and a loop over the substrings.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split your string on subcomponents using `String.split("\\|")`, but regexes won't help you to group them up in different arrays, nor will it help you to convert substrings to appropriate type. You'll need a separate logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` method.

```
 String []ar=str.split("(?=([A-Z]))");
 for(String s:ar)
   System.out.println(s.replace("|",","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler to just split then loop.
More or less:

```
String input = ...
String[] splitted = input.split("|");
List<String[]> resultArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] currentArray = null;
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        currentArray = new String[5];
        resultArrays.put(currentArray);
    }
    currentArray[i%5] = splitted[i];
}
```

Comment: `input.split("|");` won't work as intended, as this is a regex OR symbol; `\\|` should be used instead.

Comment: The `split()` pattern is supposed to be a regex, and `|` is a regex metacharacter, so you need to escape it: `"\\|"`.  Also, you the method to add an element to a List is `add()`, not `put()`.